# When I create a react app I get an error: node:fs:1380 const result = binding.mkdir(

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, typescript, npm

By entering the command:

```
create-react-app my-app --template typescript
```

Then an error appears:

```
node:fs:1380
  const result = binding.mkdir(
                         ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'D:\jwt-auth\my-app'
    at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1380:26)
    at module.exports.makeDirSync (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\make-dir.js:23:13)
    at createApp (C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:257:6)
    at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:223:9
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: 'D:\\jwt-auth\\my-app'
}

Node.js v20.11.0
```

Please help me. I tried all the methods and nothing helped

Comment: Try running the command as administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says it all:

> operation not permitted, mkdir 'D:\jwt-auth\my-app'

The user you are running the command with does not have the necessary permissions to create a directory at the path specified. Either run it with an administrator, or a user who has the necessary privileges or grant the user you are about to run this command the necessary privileges.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [latest official React documentation](https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project), there are two methods to install React.js: using a framework (such as Next.js, Remix, or Gatsby) or without a framework (using Vite or Parcel).

To start a new React project with Vite, you can use the following command:

```bash
npm create vite@latest
```

For more information, you can refer to the Vite documentation: https://vitejs.dev/guide/

This command will prompt the installation process for Vite, allowing you to set up and begin your React project easily.